# What can we say about the square of an element of $H^2(U) \cap H^1_0(U)$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ be open, connected with smooth boundary and $u \in H^2(\Omega) \cap H^1_0(\Omega)$. It's well known that $H^2(\Omega)$ is an algebra and thus $u^2 \in H^2(\Omega)$. Does it follow that $u^2 \in H^2_0(\Omega)$?

Comment: If $u$ is compactly supported, is $u^2$ also?

Comment: Yes, but I don't think it's quite so simple.

Comment: Give the definitions.

Comment: Sure, $u \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ if there exists smooth compactly supported functions $(u_n)$ such that $\lVert u - u_n \rVert_{H^1(\Omega)} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ while $u \in H^2_0(\Omega)$  if there exists smooth compactly supported functions $(u_n)$ such that $\lVert u - u_n \rVert_{H^2(\Omega)} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: If there is a counterexample, it is a function that vanishes on $\partial \Omega$ but whose first derivative does not vanish on $\partial \Omega$.

Comment: We have $u^2 \in H^2(\Omega)$. I guess $u^2|_{\partial \Omega} = u|_{\partial \Omega}^2 = 0$(?) and $(u^2)_{x_i} = 2 u u_{x_i}$ also vanishes on $\partial \Omega$(?) Then from the characterization of $H_0^2(\Omega)$, we obtain $u^2 \in H_0^2(\Omega)$.

Comment: @Kakashi This is why I think what I wrote "should" be true but I think the statement 
$$\left. u^2 \right|_{\partial \Omega} = \left( \left. u \right|_{\partial \Omega} \right)^2$$
is at least a bit tricky because its really a statement about the trace operator.

Comment: The statement $\tau(u^2) = \tau(u)^2$ is true for $u \in H^2(\Omega)$ since both sides are continuous maps from $H^2(\Omega)$ to $H^{1.5}(\partial \Omega)$. So $u^2 \in H^2(\Omega) \cap H_0^1(\Omega)$ at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\tau$ be the restriction map from $\Omega$ to $\partial \Omega$. We have $\tau(\phi^2) = \tau(\phi)^2$ for $\phi \in C^{\infty}(\overline{\Omega})$. Note $$u \in H^2(\Omega) \implies u^2 \in H^2(\Omega) \implies \tau(u^2) \in H^{1.5}(\partial \Omega)$$
and
$$u \in H^2(\Omega) \implies \tau(u) \in H^{1.5}(\partial \Omega) \implies \tau(u)^2 \in H^{1.5}(\partial \Omega).$$
Thus $\tau(u^2) = \tau(u)^2 = 0$ holds by continuity.
Next, let $\phi_n \in C^{\infty}(\overline{\Omega})$ with $\phi_n \to u$ in $H^2(\Omega)$, and pass to subsequences so that all $L^2$ convergences happen almost everywhere. We have $(\phi_n^2)_{x_i} = 2\phi_n (\phi_n)_{x_i}$ so $\tau((\phi_n^2)_{x_i}) = 2\tau(\phi_n)\tau((\phi_n)_{x_i}) \to 2\tau(u)\tau(u_{x_i})=0$ almost everywhere. Since $\tau((\phi_n^2)_{x_i}) \to \tau((u^2)_{x_i})$, we conclude $\tau((u^2)_{x_i}) = 0$. By exercise 3 on page 343 of "Partial Differential Equations I" by Taylor, we conclude $u^2 \in H^2_0(\Omega)$

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Kakashi, posting my final proof for completeness (with $|u|^2$ rather than $u^2$).

Lemma:
Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ be a bounded domain with
smooth boundary and let
$$u \in H^2(\Omega) \cap H^1_0(\Omega)\, .$$
Then $|u|^2 \in H^2_0(\Omega)$.

Proof:
It is an elementary exercise to show that $H^2(\Omega)$ is an algebra
and thus $|u|^2 \in H^2(\Omega)$.
Recall that by definition $H^k_0(\Omega)$ is the closure of $C^\infty_0(\Omega)$
in $H^k(\Omega)$.
For $\Omega$ with smooth boundary, we have the characterization
$u \in H^2_0(\Omega)$ if and only if $\tau \left( a(\hat{x}) \cdot \nabla u + b(\hat{x})\, u \right) = 0$
for all $a \in C^\infty(\Omega; \mathbb{R}^3)$ and $b \in C^\infty(\Omega)$
where $\tau$ is the trace operator mapping $H^1(\Omega)$ to $H^\frac{1}{2}(\partial \Omega)$
(see Exercise 3, p. 343 of Taylor's Partial Differential Equations I).

Since $u \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ there exists a sequence $(u_n) \subseteq C^\infty_c(\Omega)$
such that $u_n \to u$ in $H^1(\Omega)$
while since $u \in H^2(\Omega)$ there exists a sequence $(v_n) \subseteq C^\infty(\Omega)$
such that $v_n \to u$ in $H^2(\Omega)$.

We then have
$$\left\lVert |u|^2 - \bar{v}_n u_n \right\rVert_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq \lVert \bar{u} \rVert_{L^\infty(\Omega)} \lVert u - u_n \rVert_{L^2(\Omega)} + \lVert \bar{u} - \bar{v}_n \rVert_{L^\infty(\Omega)} \lVert u_n \rVert_{L^2(\Omega)} \to 0$$
as $n \to \infty$
and similarly
\begin{align*}
    \left\lVert \nabla \left( |u|^2 - \bar{v}_n u_n \right) \right\rVert_{L^2(\Omega)} &= \lVert \bar{u} \nabla u + u \nabla \bar{u} - \bar{v}_n \nabla u_n - u_n \nabla \bar{v}_n \rVert_{L^2(\Omega)} \\
    &\leq \lVert \bar{u} \rVert_{L^\infty(\Omega)} \lVert \nabla (u - u_n) \rVert_{L^2(\Omega)} + \lVert \bar{u} - \bar{v}_n \rVert_{L^\infty(\Omega)} \lVert \nabla u_n \rVert_{L^2(\Omega)} \\
    &\qquad \qquad + \lVert u \rVert_{L^\infty(\Omega)} \lVert \nabla (\bar{u} - \bar{v}_n) \rVert_{L^2(\Omega)} + \lVert u - u_n \rVert_{L^4(\Omega)} \lVert \nabla \bar{v}_n \rVert_{L^4(\Omega)}
  \end{align*}
which also converges to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

It follows that $u_n \bar{v}_n \to |u|^2$ in $H^1(\Omega)$ and thus
by continuity of the trace operator $\tau \left( a(\hat{x}) \cdot \nabla \left( u_n \bar{v}_n \right) + b(\hat{x})\, u_n \bar{v}_n \right) \to \tau \left( a(\hat{x}) \cdot \nabla |u|^2 + b(\hat{x})\, |u|^2 \right)$
but $\tau \left( a(\hat{x}) \cdot \nabla \left( u_n \bar{v}_n \right) + b(\hat{x})\, u_n \bar{v}_n \right) = 0$
for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and thus $\tau \left( a(\hat{x}) \cdot \nabla |u|^2 + b(\hat{x})\, |u|^2 \right) = 0$.
We conclude that $|u|^2 \in H^2_0(\Omega)$.